# How to run a task without login using Autoit after reboot of the machine

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, autoit

I have two tasks `test1` and `test2`. `test1` is for system start up and `test2` is for log on.

Everything works fine until a restart of the machine happens. When a restart happens and I don't login no task is running. Is there any way to solve this issue?

**Test1:**

```
Local $taskName = 'test1'
_TaskExists($taskName)
If @error = 0 Then
    _trace("Task " & $taskName & " exists: updating...")
    RunWait("schtasks /DELETE /F /TN " & $taskName, $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
    RunWait("schtasks /CREATE /F /TN " & $taskName & " /TR " & '"' & @ScriptFullPath & '"' & " /SC ONSTART /RL HIGHEST ", $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
Else
    _trace("Task " & $taskName & " does not exist: creating...")
    RunWait("schtasks /CREATE /F /TN " & $taskName & " /TR " & '"' & @ScriptFullPath & '"' & " /SC ONSTART /RL HIGHEST ", $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
    If @error Then
        _error("Task " & $taskName & " was not created successfully: " & @error)
    EndIf
EndIf
```

**Test2:**

```
Local $taskName = 'test2'
_TaskExists($taskName)
If @error = 0 Then
    _trace("Task " & $taskName & " exists: updating...")
    RunWait("schtasks /DELETE /F /TN " & $taskName, $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
    RunWait("schtasks /CREATE /F /TN " & $taskName & " /TR " & '"' & @ScriptFullPath & '"' & " /SC ONLOGON /RL HIGHEST", $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
    If @error Then
        _error("Task " & $taskName & " was not updated successfully: " & @error)
    EndIf
Else
    _trace("Task " & $taskName & " does not exist: creating...")
    RunWait("schtasks /CREATE /F /TN " & $taskName & " /TR " & '"' & @ScriptFullPath & '"' & " /SC ONLOGON /RL HIGHEST", $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
    If @error Then
        _error("Task " & $taskName & " was not created successfully: " & @error)
    EndIf
EndIf
```

Comment: Are you saying that *test1* runs if you start the machine from scratch but not if you perform a restart?

Comment: Yes Chenmuka , Because for first time if launch the script it works perfectly ,i expect it to work for n restarts .After restart also it works but only after login . I have identified the reason also because the the task is being created with "Run only when user logged in". If you know how to solve this ..Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the script with *Aut2Exe* and setting the resulting exe to run at startup?

Comment: It didnt work ..:(

Comment: Try `schtasks` switch `/RU System`. Remember: there is no GUI at this point, so if you want to automate a GUI program, you'll have to wait until a user logs in.